# Write Input from Entry Widget into CSV (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What I want is a simple Widget that adds the value entered in the Entry together with the date and time into a cvs file like this:

```
2016-02-22 11:40    12  
2016-02-22 11:43    549
2016-02-22 11:44    321
```

My Code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import csv
import datetime

def enter_button():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    amount = e1.get()# That is where I thought I should get the Input from the widget
    with open('File.csv', 'a') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f,dialect='excel-tab')
        w.writerow([now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), amount]) # write Date/Time and the value
f.close()

master = Tk()
e1 = Entry(master)
Label(master, text='Enter Number Here').grid(row=0)
myButton=Button(master,text='Enter',command=enter_button())
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
myButton.grid(row=1,column=0)
mainloop()
```

the code runs and I the widget looks like this:
[image]

the problem is that the value from the Entry field is not written into the cvs file.... I only get the date and the time the button (`myButton`) was pressed....
Those are written into the `.csv`file.
So what did I miss to get the value from the Entry field into the function (`enter_button`)? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are calling the `enter_button` function

```
myButton = Button(master, text='Enter',command=enter_button())
                                                          ^^^
```

You need to specify the function name to the `command` option.

```
myButton = Button(master, text='Enter', command=enter_button)
```

Also you don't need to call `f.close()` because the `with` statement takes care of that for you.